# nautilus doesn't start under heavy load

Tags: nautilus

When my system running Ubuntu 14.04 is under a heavy load (for instance a long video encode) nautilus fails to start. I've seen this similar question: [Nautilus occasionally stops working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618171/nautilus-occasionally-stops-working)

But although the error when launched in terminal is identical, `Could not register the application: Timeout was reached` it doesn't appear to apply in this case.

I tried all the answers in the aforementioned similar question.

Results are as follows

```
me@zippy-64bit:~$ killall nautilus
me@zippy-64bit:~$ nautilus -q
Could not register the application: Timeout was reached

me@zippy-64bit:~$ killall nautilus
me@zippy-64bit:~$ nautilus
Could not register the application: Timeout was reached
```

I ran a nautilus self-check with the following results:

```
me@zippy-64bit:~$ nautilus -c
running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory
running nautilus_self_check_file
running nautilus_self_check_canvas_container
running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory
running nautilus_self_check_file
running nautilus_self_check_canvas_container
```

`gvfs-mount` shows no remote mounts as seen below.

```
me@zippy-64bit:~$ gvfs-mount -l
Drive(0): TOSHIBA THNSNH128GBST
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
  Volume(0): 13 GB Volume
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Drive(1): WDC WD2003FZEX-00Z4SA0
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Drive(2): WDC WD3001FAEX-00MJRA0
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Drive(3): Optiarc DVD RW AD-7280S
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
me@zippy-64bit:~$ man nautilus
me@zippy-64bit:~$ nautilus
Could not register the application: Timeout was reached
```

`gksu nautilus` launches instantly perhaps due to a super user task being launched at higher priority.

I'd like to determine if extending the timeout under these conditions would allow nautilus to open. Is there a way I can accomplish this or **any other effective workaround**? Ideally I'd like to accomplish this without interrupting the encoding job currently running.

Comment: Use something lighter than Nautilus, like `mc`.

Comment: @Pilot6 There's a thought. I've become fairly accustomed to some of the features in nautilus that assist my workflow such as open, open with, bookmarks and such. It doesn't seem that `mc` has these features. Am I missing something? Is there a closer relative with similar features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was resolved by installing nemo as suggested by [@Fabby](https://askubuntu.com/users/344926/fabby) in a [comment here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618171/nautilus-occasionally-stops-working#comment887485_618171)

I installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libnemo-extension1 nemo-data nemo-fileroller
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnemo-extension1 nemo nemo-data nemo-fileroller
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,075 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,116 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

Further research  indicates that I was affected by [this bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1290310) IF you are also affected please subscribe to the bug so that the developers can get a sense of it's impact and budget their time accordingly.